# user reference in the profile model or reference of the profile in the user model

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

*The driver for accessing my mongoDB database is mongoose, but this question is for all people, regardless of the programming language used.* 
I created a user's schema, where I keep the username, password, email ... and a schema of the profile. It is better to connect (via _id) the profile to the user or the user to the profile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your usecase.

If you wish to find a user based on the content of their profile, then you will need a `Profile.user_id`.

If, on the other hand, you wish to find a profile for a specific user, then `User.profile_id` would be required.

If your usecase requires both operations, then add both fields.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer